# How to redirect user to the developer page in the Market?

Tags: android, google-play

I use this code to redirect user to a particular app in the Market:

```
Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName);
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

How can I redirect user to a developer page in the Market?
I tried copy link from browser to the Uri

```
Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://developer?id=Developer+Name");
```

real name has been changed
This causes Fatal exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime(29775): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent
```

I can use

```
Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Developer+Name");
```

but application selection dialog appears (Play Market or Browser). I want to use the market by default.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct query is:

```
 market://search?q=pub:\"IncrediApp\"
```

Regarding your errors:

> This causes Fatal exception

This is because you're probably running it on an emulator or a device which doesn't have the Google Play app installed.

> but application selection dialog appears (Play Market or Browser). I want to use the market by default.

If you use the market:// prefix it would be the default. For https://play.google.com it works according to the user' settings and would ask the user if no default is defined.